# Merge [survival] into [survival-analysis]?

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

From the tag excerpts and browsing tagged questions, it seems clear to me that [survival](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/survival)

> Survival analysis compares the statistical strength of predictors for events encoded as occuring or censored in concert with a timevariable. It can be parametric or non-parametric.

and [survival-analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/survival-analysis)

> Survival analysis is the statistics of censored time to event data, to  which standard regression and classification techniques generally do not apply, due to the uncertain group memberships of the observations. The name originated from biological systems where the outcome of interest was indeed survival or death, but the concept applies equally well to mechanical failure, economic events or other types of prognostication.

refer to the same thing. [survival-analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/survival-analysis) is the more popular tag, with ~1050 questions compared to [survival](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/survival)'s ~350, (137 have both tags). I think [survival-analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/survival-analysis) is also a more appropriate name. Could we merge [survival](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/survival) into [survival-analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/survival-analysis)?

Comment: We need some evolution related pun for the title :)

Comment: @klutt _On the Origin of Tags by Means of Natural Burnination, or the Preservation of Favoured Aliases in the Struggle for Life_